# adding a div block to a wordpress loop when no posts are found in a category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress loop I'm running that shows content for posts in a certain category. I need to show some content if there is no posts but don't know enough php to know how to set up the if/else statement.

Here's the loop:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'cat' => ('5'),
);

// The Query
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="company-logo-openings-closings"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
<div class="opening-closings-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">LEARN MORE</a></div>
<div style="width: 100%; clear: both; height: 50px;"></div>


<?php endwhile; 

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

I essentially want the above to insert `<div>CONTENT GOES HERE</div>` if there are no posts in the stated category.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wp_Query Format

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```